# Trailhead - LWC Open Source - displays blank page

Tags: lightning-web-components, trailhead, open-source

I'm working on the #DF19 Developer Keynote Highlights Trailmix, in the Build Your First Application with Lightning Web Components Open Source -> Modify the Default Application chapter.

I followed the instructions EXACTLY, and was able to get the default application up & running, but when I started the customizations, the templates aren't being injected into my html.

Localhost is running, and it loads a blank page. The html in the inspector tools is:

```
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Lightning Conference</title>
<style>
  body {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
</style>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/resources/favicon.ico">


</head>
  <body>
    <div id="main"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/lwc~main.app.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/node_vendors~main.app.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/app.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Note that nothing was inserted between the open and close div tags for the div id = main.

The only error in the js console is:

```
localhost/:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

There's a note in the module about checking if 'watch' has been terminated, but that can't be it because I've manually reloaded the page a number of times and nothing has changed, and likewise restarted the server.

Has anyone else started this module?

Comment: Have you checked on the Trailhead Community through the [Trailhead Help](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help), perhaps someone else has the same issue.

Comment: Thanks @DavidCheng, I posted there too.